# Matplotlib histogram does not show details of distribution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, histogram

I have some data and I would like to look at its distribution. But I don't know why when I use this code, the histogram does not really show what is going on within the data and it shows a very general picture. I want to have a more granular histogram.

```
data['feature'].plot(kind='hist')
```

And here is what this code gives me:

**histogram**:

[image: histogram]

How can I make it more granular?

Comment: Look at the `bins` argument of the `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html

Comment: Try passing something like `bins=32` to `.plot()` (or some other number)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without knowing what your are trying to plot (example data/input) it is going to be hard to help. Please read [mcve], [ask] and the other links on that page.

Comment: My data has 10000 records. I can't really type it here. But is  mostly between 0 and 5 and there are also some values around 10, 20, 30 and larger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bins` parameter will take a sequence of bin edges and supports unequal spaced bins. Construct a sequence that will give you finer granularity where most of your data is

```
data['feature'].plot(kind='hist', bins=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,
                                        1.0,...
                                        9.1,9.2,9.3,9.4,9.5,9.6,9.7,9.8,9.9,10,
                                        20, 30)
```

or

```
data.plot.hist(by='feature', bins=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,
                                   1.0,...
                                   9.1,9.2,9.3,9.4,9.5,9.6,9.7,9.8,9.9,
                                   10, 20, 30)
```

---

You can manufacture the bins argument with numpy.linspace and numpy.concatenate:

```
bins = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0,10,num=101), [20,30]))
```

Comment: That is amazing. Thank

Answer (score 1):

`data['feature'].plot(kind='hist', bins=100)`

This would group histogram into 100 bins. If you need even higher granularity you can naturally use higher number.

---

Your data seems very left-skewed. You can force 100 bins with equal number of member, using `pd.qcut` as `bins` parameter:

`_, bins = pd.qcut(data['feature'], 100, retbins=True)`
`data['feature'].plot(kind='hist', bins=bins)`

Comment: This did not solve the problem and it only made the histogram thinner

Comment: Could you post example of ghe data you are dealing with? Seems like you have very left skewed data. You can pass `logx=True` argument to the function.